# Use strings from a function to main function

Tags: c, arrays, function, char, c-strings

One of my functions reads lines from a text file and stores into a variable. I need a way to use that variable in my main function. I've tried several methods and nothing has worked. Can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int test(const char *fname, char **names){

    char usernames[250][50];
    FILE *infile;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    int i =0;

    infile = fopen(fname, "r");


    while(fgets(buffer,50,infile)){
        strcpy(usernames[i],buffer);
        printf("%s",usernames[i]);
        i++;
    }

    int x, y;
    for(y = 0; y < 250; y++)
        for(x = 0; x < 50; x++)
            usernames[y][x] = names[y][x];

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    char *names;
    test("test.txt", &names);
}
```

Can anyone help? I haven't coded in C in a long time.

Comment: To start, you don't allocate space for `names`.

Answer (score 2):

In C, the caller should allocate the memory for the strings it needs, otherwise, no one knows who's supposed to free memory. Then you can pass a pointer to a function that will populate it.

```
int main() {
    char names[250][50];
    test("test.txt", names);
    for (int i=0; i < 50; i++) {
        printf("File %d: %s", i, names[i], 250);
    }     
}


void test(const char *fname, char(*names)[50], int maxWords){

    FILE *infile;
    int i =0;
    char buffer[50];

    infile = fopen(fname, "r");

    while(fgets(buffer,50,infile) && i < maxWords){
        strcpy(usernames[i],names[i]);
        i++;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Erm... this won't compile with strict "warning-as-errors". The type of `names` is not compatible with `char**`. You should specify names in `test`s prototype as `char(*names)[50]` and pass `250` as well for bounds checking.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks, fixed it, I couldn't remember the syntax for `char(*names)[50]` it's been about 12 years since I wrote any C

Comment: @shix "Won't compile" without an error message doesn't help... Also, I believe there is already enough to answer the question